# Alexa - By canFulfillntentRequest, Can I launch custom intent without asking the name of skill?

Tags: alexa-skills-kit, alexa-voice-service

By implementing the "canFulfillIntentRequest", Can I launch my custom intent without asking the name of skill while it is already playing an audio? like instead of saying:

```
"Alexa, ask <inovation name> to get me the latest on China"
```

can I say?

```
"Alexa, get me the latest on China"
```

Any help will be highly appreciable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the skill is invoked and is already playing the audio then it depends on the variable `shouldEndSession`. If `shouldEndSession` variable is set to `True`, while playing the audio file then **NO**, otherwise **YES**. You could ask at the end of the audio file, it the user wants to hear more or something.

And if the skill is not invoked, then it is not possible.

Comment: Thanks for the valuable comment. I'll try checking it.